# Can the Sabre Vcard Library handle Profile Photos ( images )

Tags: php, sabre, card

Using the Sabre PHP Library for handling Vcards. We're successfully using the library for sending and receiving Vcards but I can't find anything on handling profile photos/images. Am I totally missing something in there or is it not set up for that.

Comment: Any link to the library and can you share the code have tried and stacked with?